# Boostrap 5 dropdown not working when adding specific line in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I have this dropdown which shows several buttons, one of them opens a modal. The dropdown is in the template of app-component and the modal is in the template of login-modal.

app.component.html:

```
<app-login-modal (validLogin)="changeCredentials($event)"></app-login-modal>

<div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2">
        <strong>mdo</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal" *ngIf="!this.logged">Log in</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()" type="button" *ngIf="this.logged">Log out</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

It works perfectly until I add this line of code in the component of the login modal:

login-modal.component.ts

```
    let modal : bootstrap.Modal | null = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modalElement!);
```

After adding that line, the dropdow does not show anymore. Why?

PD: angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
              "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

I really cant understand why a line of code which is not even in the same component is breaking my dropdown menu

Comment: Is `let modal :` valid syntax with Typescript? I'd have expected `let modal =`.

Comment: What I'm really asking is whether you have console errors.

Comment: yes, it is. The console is not showing anything